# PhpStorm PDOStatement Warnings

Tags: php, pdo, phpstorm

Consider the following class:

```
class output_Home {
    public $app;
    public $forums;

    function __construct ($app) {
        // main app class containing db, settings, etc
        $this->app = $app;

        // populate class property arrays for use in template
        $this->setForums();
    }

    function setForums () {
        /*
         * select all forum data, dump into $this->forums array
         * fields:
         *      id, name, slug, description, order,
         *      total_threads, total_posts,
         *      last_post_id, last_post_date, last_poster_id, last_poster_username, last_poster_avatar
         */
        $sql = "select f.*,
                p.id as last_post_id, p.date_created as last_post_date,
                u.id as last_poster_id, u.username as last_poster_username, u.avatar as last_poster_avatar,
                (select count(*) from `threads` where `id_forum`=f.id) as total_threads,
                (select count(*) from `posts` where `id_forum`=f.id) as total_posts
                from `forums` as f
                left join `posts` as p on (p.id = (select `id` from `posts` where `id_forum`=f.id order by `date_created` desc limit 1))
                left join `users` as u on (u.id = p.id_user)
                order by f.order asc";
        $stm = $this->app->db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute();
        $this->forums = $this->app->sanitizer->action('sanitize', $stm->fetchAll());
    }
}
```

Here is my `object_App` class:

```
class object_App {
    public $db;

    function __construct () {
        // create database "db" connection
        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

Here is how `$this->app` is passed to the `output_Home` class:

```
$app = new object_App();
$home = new output_Home($app);
```

The `$app` property contains a property called `db`, which is a PDO object. Notice the `$stm` variable in particular here.

My problem is that I am getting warnings from PhpStorm claiming that methods such as `$stm->execute()` are not found in the class. Well of course they aren't, because they are `PDOStatements`.

I just want to know if there is a way I can get rid of the warnings properly, without using `PHPDocs` above every single `$stm` I make, because I will be making quite a few in several different class methods, and I don't want `PHPDocs` everywhere in the code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How's your `app->db` is defined? SO far it does not look like it's PDO (in eyes of PhpStorm, of course). Show the definition. Also show what PhpStorm thinks about it -- place caret on `db` in `$this->app->db` and invoke Ctrl+Q (View | Quick Documentation) and show a screenshot of it. If your `db` is properly documented .. then you should not see this error (and there will be no need to use PHPDoc for inline variables like `$stm`).

Comment: I edited the OP showing how $this->app->db is defined and how $this->app is passed to the class.

Comment: That's great - now show what "View | Quick Documentation" shows you (when you are inside your `output_Home` class; just as per my comment above).

Comment: $stm 
Source: 

.../classes/output/Home.php

Comment: I was asking about `$db` and not `$smt` ... In any case -- see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Provide proper type hint for `$db`. In your particular case this may not be 100% necessary, but better have it (it's one time job)

```
class object_App {
    /** @var \PDO */
    public $db;
    ...
```

In general IDE can figure out what `$db` is because you have `$this->db = new PDO(...);` and it's located in `__construct()` (2 important factors).. but it's better be on safer side with proper type hint. if such line would be placed in some ordinary method (e.g. `createDBConnection()` or something, IDE will not do that costly extra intelligence.

**2.** Most importantly -- provide type hint for your `$app`. The way how you are passing this argument gives no hints for IDE.

It could be done like this (and IDE should figure out the rest):

```
function __construct (object_App $app) {
```

Or better in a same way as in #1:

```
class output_Home {
    /** @var object_App */
    public $app;
```

or even better -- combine them together:

```
class output_Home {
    /** @var object_App */
    public $app;

    function __construct (object_App $app) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

unless PHPStorm knows what type of object a method returns, it has no way of knowing what methods might be available to that object.

you have 3 options:

1) as you stated, use a quick phpdoc to tell phpstorm what it is (you only need to do this once in a code block:

```
/** @var SomeObject $stm */
$stm = $this->app->db->prepare($sql);
```

2) supress the warning altogether

find:

settings > editor > inspections

then untick `undefined method` under PHP > undefined.

3) if you have control of the method being called:

make sure that you include the return type in the phpdoc for the method, PHPStorm will use that to determine what it needs.

```
/**
* @return SomeObject
*/
public function someFunction() {
   // some stuff
}
```

Comment: I figured. I do not want to uncheck undefined method warnings as they are highly useful. I'll probably just go the PHPDoc route.

Comment: Option one is what you should be doing, this is called "type hinting".

Comment: `/** var $stm PDOStatement */` is what I was using, I just didn't want it all over the place in my code.